# jQuery Mobile a href not navigating to div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, hyperlink, href

Hi I'm fairly new with jQuery and I am making a jQuery mobile site

I have used the data-role to define the role of each div. I have my navigation bar which I want to link to the divs that sit below the "main content" div. On my main site I can navigate to the divs below perfectly. However when I try to navigate to the divs below on the main site I get no where. The hyperlinks seem not to work.

Is there a different method to link to the divs below on the same page when using jQuery mobile as I know it works on my normal website?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="c" > <!--Start Nav Div -->
        <ul>
        <li><a data-icon="home" data-rel="dialog"  href="indexmobile.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a  data-icon="arrow-d" data-rel="dialog" href="#aboutme">About</a></li>
        <li><a  data-icon="grid" data-rel="dialog" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a data-icon="gear" data-rel="dialog" href="#contactform">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div> <!-- End Nav Div -->
    </div> <!-- End Header Div -->

    <div id="maincontent" data-role="content"> <!-- Main Content Div -->
    </div> <!-- End Main Content -->
     <div id="portfolio"> <!-- Start Portfolio Div -->

            </div> <!--- End Portfolio Div -->

        <div id="aboutme"> <!--- About Me Div Start -->

        </div> <!--- End About Me Div -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the kind of anchor-linking to divs that you require you could simply add this to your links:

```
data-ajax="false"
```

This basically tells the framework not to use ajax, it will prompt the browser to treat the '#aboutme' anchor as it was originally intended - to identify a part of a page to display.

Using this technique you can still have lots of scrollable content on the same page and still link to it with navbars or footers or what have you.

The accepted answer isn't really solving your problem - it's telling you to create a multi-page document instead, thereby bypassing the problem, as you won't have the scrollable content you presumably required in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your `<div>` should be a different `data-role="page"`.

Read the section on [Linking within a multi-page document](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html) in JQueryMobile docs.

Comment: I just tried this like so
`<div id="about" data-role="content"> </div>` and this still did not work. Is there anything else you could recommend?

Comment: `<div id="about" data-role="page">` You will have to repeat your `<div data-role="header">` and `<div data-role="content">` under each one.

Comment: No this is not the case, I read the link that you send me and I have found the answer. I had to add this into the <a> tag `rel="external"`. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: When you do a `rel="external"` you are telling JQM to download the link as a separate page... essentially reloading the entire page every time.

Comment: You could use data-ajax="false" - see my answer